# Can someone use DC generator along with electric motor to make electricity along with mechanical energy?

Tags: electric-circuits

I know this might sound stupid and maybe stupid totally, but I need some clarification....

I came through electric motor principle.

and then I came across the following link on DC generators
[DC Generator](http://www.ncert.nic.in/html/learning_basket/electricity/electricity/machine/dc_generator.htm)

Now my question is, can't we combine them both to provide DC current with little DC used in motor side? By "combine," I mean using a DC generator coil only at the other side of the coil of the motor in the motor itself. The condition is that the 2 coils are connected via some apparatus that causes the 2nd coil to move along with the 1st coil.

[image: Mechanism proposed]
In this way we can use both the mechanical energy produced by the 1st coil and the electrical energy produced by the 2nd coil, right?

This is a great concept if it works, right? Please throw some light on this.

Comment: Yes, you can use a motor to drive a generator. It is a cheap way to, for example, make 3-phase power at home without running 3-phase power to the house panel (which is unusual in residential practice). And, yes, you have rotation of the shaft, so you could run a belt from it as well. But you don't get out more power than you put in.

Comment: The law of conservation of energy still has to hold... You will get no more energy (electrical + mechanical) out than you put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Pranshu Malick* is correct. You cannot have a perfectly efficient closed energy system. It would be like trying to move forward in a submarine that had a thrust propeller on the back and a input "generator" propeller on the front, and expecting that once you get going the front will always power the back, and the back the front, and so on.
  You are, however, correct in assuming that there is energy that would normally be wasted that can be collected and reused. In some hybrid cars part of the braking system involves engaging generators, reducing the "wasted energy" of negative acceleration.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the answer. Also, I wanted to ask, since you talked about cars part's energy generation, that can't there be a system that consumes rotation of the wheels of the car like generator(like connecting the rotating wheels to a dynamo or something?). I love reusing energy that is why came up with this idea.

Comment: Yes, you could do that. But again you're spending energy that you've generated... to generate more energy.  Now obviously in gasoline engines they have a generator to keep powering the windows, spark plugs and sensors. That's just converting the available gas power of the car into electricity.     The best way to conserve energy is to re-collect all  the energy that is not being used for the sole purpose of the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please be specific about the coils? In case you are referring to the coil inside the motor and dividing it into two halves, then that won't be possible since current needs a loop to flow, and you can't have a closed loop while just having mechanical motion and no current in one loop. 
Further, there are always frictional and resistive losses, so the initial energy provided (in the form of rotating the coils at first) it will eventually die out, and will need a driving source - a battery or rotating turbines. 
You can't create energy and (or) have 100% efficiency in a cyclic process, violates the second law of thermodynamics as well as the law of conservation of energy.

Comment: added the image you requested

Comment: Okay, so what you are saying is to have a shaft extending from the DC (powered) motor to the coil 2 and further to use electricity as well as the rotation provided.

Comment: That will be still the same, but with the extended losses, the net power you get will be less than what the  battery provides

Comment: yes. The 1st shaft rotates and then because it is attached to the 2nd coil, the 2nd coil rotates and produces electricity.

Comment: but I can still have "some" electrical energy along with mechanical energy?

Comment: The more loads you connect, in totality the net power delivered will equal the loss and the produced. If, for example you have a pulley and the coil 2. Then as the motor rotates, the current produced in the coil will resist motion (due to lenz law) and also the pulley will reduce the speed of rotation. Thus making the net power equal (assuming all resistance and friction to be non existent)